# Passing list to function as parameter

Tags: vb.net

I have a function that will perform work on a list, but I cannot get it to accept more than one datatype. For example:

```vb
Public Sub PopulateListBox (objectList as List(of VariantType), ListboxToPopulate as Listbox)
    listboxToPopulate.Items.Clear() 'clears the items in the listbox

    For Each item In objectList
        listboxToPopulate.Items.Add(item.ToString)
    Next
End
```

The problem is that I have lists of different classes, like employee, building address, etc. I cannot pass a `List(Of EmployeeClass)` because it says it cannot be converted to `List(Of VariantType)`. I have also tried `List(Of Object)` and the same result.

Comment: If your lists share characteristics, do they also share inheritance?

Comment: Have you looked at Generics?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/data-types/generic-types

Comment: You need a covariant type, `objectList As IEnumerable(Of Object)` gets the job done.

Comment: Hans, that seems to work, thank you very much. Can you post that so I can mark it as answered? Also, before I mark it as answered, can you tell me why that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will demonstrate the use by first showing you a sample class.

```
Public Class Coffee
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Type As String
    Public Sub New(iid As Integer, sname As String, stype As String)
        ID = iid
        Name = sname
        Type = stype
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Name
    End Function
End Class
```

I added a parameterized constructor just to make it easy to get a fully populate Coffee. You need to add the .ToString override so the list box will know what to display.

Here is where my List(Of Coffee) comes from.

```
Private Function FillCoffeeList() As List(Of Coffee)
    Dim CoffeeList As New List(Of Coffee)
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection),
            cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Top 10 ID, Name, Type From Coffees;", cn)
        cn.Open()
        Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            Do While reader.Read
                Dim c As New Coffee(reader.GetInt32(0), reader.GetString(1), reader.GetString(2))
                CoffeeList.Add(c)
            Loop
        End Using
    End Using
    Return CoffeeList
End Function
```

As commented by Hans Passant, change the datatype of objectList to IEnumerable(Of Object).

```
Public Sub PopulateListBox(objectList As IEnumerable(Of Object), ListboxToPopulate As ListBox)
    ListboxToPopulate.Items.Clear() 'clears the items in the listbox

    For Each item In objectList
        ListboxToPopulate.Items.Add(item)
    Next
End Sub
```

Now I can pass a List(Of Coffee) to the PopulateListBox method.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim CList = FillCoffeeList()
    PopulateListBox(CList, ListBox1)
End Sub
```

I can access the properties of the underlying type be casting.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim t = ListBox1.SelectedItem.GetType
    Select Case t.Name
        Case "Coffee"
            Dim c = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, Coffee)
            TextBox1.Text = c.ID.ToString
            TextBox2.Text = c.Type
    End Select
End Sub
```

You can add additionsl cases depending on what types you are expecting. There is probably a better way to do this.